# The Images are disappearing when you press F5 on the website but not with enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have a strange issue, and right now I'm more curious about the why than even how to fix it.

The images are disappearing when you click refresh or F5,

when you click to the link you may see or not the images (totally random)

BUT when you press enter or go on the url (depending on your browser)
you will see the three of them,

the links:

http://belcorp.minonu.com/tips-y-consejos-para-promover-un-descanso-reparador/
http://belcorp.minonu.com/tips-tambien-recomendamos/

Any hints would be great! (the site is still not fully js and style optimized that's why you will see some styles and scripts not minified)

UPDATE ----- THIS IS HOW THE CODE LOOK ALL THREE OF THE IMAGES ARE THE SAME---

```
<div class="spb">
   <div class="demo">
   <img id="d1" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/f2.png" alt="Vainilla" onmouseover="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'NOCTURNE', 'TIPS-AROMAS', 'VAINILLA']);" width="270px" height="270px" />
    <div class="bcol1 contenthover" style="background:#ebe5d8; color:#472035;">
    <h2>Vainilla</h2>
  <p>Su suave aroma produce un efecto balsámico contra la ansiedad, el cual consigue relajar a las personas más nerviosas.</p>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: May be you need set `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @CroaToa no it's not :(, that's autogenerated code, I updated some parts of the code

Comment: It seems your js dont working correctly or does not have time to boot..

Comment: but why it does work on enter and why it isn't working (it's inside of a jquery on ready.) any clues?

Comment: becouse of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764356/what-is-the-difference-between-an-f5-refresh-of-a-page-and-pasting-that-url-in

Comment: I read that but it doesn't apply on this case, I'm not sending variables and the same thing happens when you click on the link which is the same as doing an enter =(

Comment: @CroaToa you can check by clicking on the bottom bar of http://belcorp.minonu.com/tips-y-consejos-para-promover-un-descanso-reparador/ on También te recomendamos

Comment: @CroaToa it was the answer bellow =), but still don't know why it works only with enter :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it does or not work sometimes but you should add `width="270px" height="270px"`, i tried it and it works all the time now

Comment: Note that "270px" are not valid values for width and height attributes. You should change them to 270 without the "px".