# Chrome: difference between refreshing a page and new tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have read few answers for a similar question [What is the difference between an F5 (refresh) of a page and pasting that URL in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764356/what-is-the-difference-between-an-f5-refresh-of-a-page-and-pasting-that-url-in) , but it was broadly for any browser, I want specifically for Chrome.

Here is my problem, due to a [strange bug](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1943) in chrome, users can get struck in one point which I can track cannot do anything about, even refreshing the page does not help, only solution that solves the issue is pasting url in new tab.

Now can someone please guide me how to emulate this my current tab, so I need not tell the users to click on a link that would take them to a new tab where they can continue their work.

Comment: Check whether it is helping for you http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Comment: sorry wazan, it did not help much, i want something done programatically( i.e from our side) that would resemble new tab, so the user does not have to do anything.

Comment: I have a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55039923/3683187