# how to refresh a page without losing the session using javascript and the browser console?

Tags: javascript, console, reload

I want to open a url in a new tab and refresh it using the other tab, so i'll never log out of the page! for this purpose i wrote this in the console of my browser to open a new tab and refresh it every ten seconds:

```
win1 = window.open("https://www.example.com"); //opens the page
timer1 = setInterval(function(){win1.location.href="https://www.example.com"},10*1000); //refreshes every 10 Sec.
```

The **problem** with this approach is that it kind of reopens the url rather than refreshing the page, and as long as it happens i log out of the site. [I've read that there's a difference between hitting *F5* and retyping the url in address bar and hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764356/what-is-the-difference-between-an-f5-refresh-of-a-page-and-pasting-that-url-in). and it looks like that the mentioned code doesn't really trigger the *F5* kind of action i expected. so any idea on how can i truly refresh the other tab??

Comment: Why don't you fire a MouseEvent or KeyboardEvent rather than reloading the page? The other issue you'll run into is the document's focus status. Many sites test `document.hasStatus()` in order to defeat exactly what you are attempting. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn. And then how to simulate an F5 in the other tab? I shouldn't simulate an F5 in a single tab and refresh it because in this case i will lose the console as it is a property of the window object.